# Match Unique Values Against Master dataset and Run Calculation

Tags: google-sheets, index-match

I produce a set of unique dates from a master dataset.

I'd like to find master dataset rows that match each unique date to run a calculation on corresponding cell values.

I've created a [test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TTSAbgyEYtqUlSNzW0jSEiGPveYlijI3tHKlAYT2o6Q/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate what I'm after.

I'm struggling to get the correct combination of index and match in my formula. This is what I have:

```
=INDEX($K2:K,MATCH(ARRAYFORMULA(IF($K2 = INDEX($B2:B, SUM($D2:$D) / SUM($H2:H)),"")),$K2:K,0))
```

Can someone please help me untwist this?

EDIT: SUMIF was provided as a solution for the above need, That simplified what I made overly complex.

The SUMIF approach can work - I'll wind up performing that operation on four separate values, and then division on those results.

I've edited the formula above to reflect this change

```
=INDEX($K2:K,MATCH(ARRAYFORMULA(IF($K2 = INDEX($B2:B, SUM($D2:$D * $E2:$E) / SUM($H2:H * $I2:$I)),"")),$K2:K,0))
```

Based on some of the suggested solutions, I think it was unclear in my post that I need to produce the L column value for each unique date. Apologies if this was the case.

Comment: seems like you'll have quite a lot of divide by 0 errors since column H is many 0s and it's your denominator.

Comment: Can't you just do `SUMIF(B$2:B, L2, D$2:D) / SUMIF(B$2:B, L2, H$2:H)`?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I overcomplicated this, thanks. Edited the OP for a slightly more complex need.

Comment: @MattKing data sample edited to address this. The actual dataset will not have this problem, but this wasn't well represented. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your formula. What you want in M can for example be done with `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((B$2:B = K2) * D$2:D * E$2:E)) / SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((B$2:B = K2) * H$2:H * I$2:I))`. But you formula seems to suggest looking up dates? Why are you indexing into K2:K?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on a brand new tab, try this in cell A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!F:F*Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!J:J*Sheet1!K:K},"select Col1,SUM(Col2)/SUM(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label SUM(Col2)/SUM(Col3)'Gamma Tilt'"))
```

Comment: I think my original post did not make the need clear enough. I've edited to clarity (I hope). I need to generate the L column value for each unique date within the dataset.

Comment: @jivers Okay.  simple enough.  I've adjusted my formula as follows.
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!D:D*Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!H:H*Sheet1!I:I},"select Col1,SUM(Col2)/SUM(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label SUM(Col2)/SUM(Col3)'Gamma Tilt'"))

Comment: Thx. Edited for needed calculation: =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!F:F,Sheet1!I:I,Sheet1!J:J},"select Col1,SUM(Col2*Col3)/SUM(Col4*Col5) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label SUM(Col2*Col3)/SUM(Col4*Col5)'Gamma Tilt'")). Using SUMIF highlights the need for an additional grouping: 'Strike' by 'Pull Date'. Test file edited. Order of ops is important: Open Interest * Gamma by row, then summed; divided by Put Open Interest * Put Gamma by row, then summed. The master dataset table can include multiplication columns, if multiple by row then sum is too complex for one formula.

Comment: @jivers not sure i understand, the formula in my edited answer above is working or not?  Not the formula in the comment (which got messed up by some formatting) but the formula in the actual answer.

Comment: Sorry Matt for the confusion - it doesn't produce the correct value. In the workfile, I import current day data only and against this run  'code' Open Interest * Gamma by row, then results summed; divided by Put Open Interest * Put Gamma by row, then results summed 'code' and get the correct value. Trying to determine why the QUERY doesn't. In the master dataset, SUM(Open Int) * Sum(Gamma) / SUM(Put Open Int) * SUM(Gamma) produces the same result as the QUERY statement.

Comment: @jivers Alright I've updated my answer here one more time. And i made a copy of your sheet which is here with the formula in cell P1.  Hopefully having a common sheet we can both edit will help?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bVwvY3P-Bys4jpxccDSUP4zU6rwq4iBZ7EB8crgZui0/edit#gid=0

Comment: OK, that's producing the correct result in the master dataset. I'll run it later against today's data. Thanks for all the help and time.